# How to decode an integer in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, type-conversion, format, hex

I have a method that prints labels from a Web Application in MVC5, for this I am using the Neodinamyc plugin

The problem is that this method delivers the encoded parameters, for the first printerName parameter I was able to decode it in the following way and I succeeded

[image: Screenshoot0]

But I think that the second parameter called location that is of integer type gives it to me as hexadecimal or at least I think so, since the error says: "can not be converted from int to string"

[image: Screenshoot1]

I'm currently testing with

```
  ubicacion = Convert.ToInt32(ubicacion);
```

and it does not work for me, it still has the same value

Why do I get this hexadecimal type number when I pass an integer?
How can I convert this parameter to an integer? any help for me?

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure it is not the VS intellisense tool tip which is showing you the corresponding hex value ?

Comment: Sure, because later I still use that variable and it has the same hexadecimal value, what do you propose? @Shyju

Comment: You are getting the error when attempting to what? UrlDecode the integer? You don't need to UrlDecode an integer. UrlDecode doesn't have an overload for `Int32`.

Comment: I'm just trying to convert the number that I receive 0x00000001 an integer !! How would you do it? @JonathonChase

Comment: It's value is not a string of `0x00000001`. It's just being displayed that way. Right click the tooltip showing the `0x00000001` value and unselect hexadecimal display.

Comment: Why do not you propose your answer? it worked for me !! @JonathonChase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value doesn't need to be converted, it's already an integer.
Your tooltip is just displaying it in hexadecimal. You can change this by right-clicking the tooltip and unselecting `Hexadecimal Display`